# CMake export package that relies on external library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project written using C++ and CMake, using Boost, that I'm trying to make a standalone binary/header package for to allow other people to link against my work. I'm using cmake installers for this. However, I'm running into issues with `install(EXPORTS ...)` when my library links to an external library. In particular, the Boost library and header directory locations are hard-coded into the exported file, and I can't figure out how to make it work better.

Have an example. (Untested; if it's not clear I can elaborate or fix it.)

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
package(MyLibrary)
set(MyLibrary_VERSION 1.0)

find_component(BOOST 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization)

set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/MyLibrary/include")
set(INSTALL_SRC_DIR "C:/MyLibrary/include")
set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR "C:/MyLibrary/bin")
set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR "C:/MyLibrary/lib")
set(INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR "C:/MyLibrary/cmake")

set(HEADERS myfile.hpp)
set(SOURCES myfile.cpp)

install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR} COMPONENT headers)
install(FILES ${SOURCES} DESTINATION ${INSTALL_SRC_DIR} COMPONENT sources)

add_library(MyLibrary STATIC
    ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(MyLibrary
    ${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY})

target_include_directories(MyLibrary
    PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR};${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}>"
    PUBLIC "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include;${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}>")


install(TARGETS MyLibrary EXPORT MyLibrary-depends
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_DIR} COMPONENT libraries)

configure_package_config_file(MyLibraryConfig.cmake.in
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibraryConfig.cmake" 
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
write_basic_package_version_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibraryConfigVersion.cmake" 
    VERSION ${MyLibrary_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion)

install(FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibraryConfig.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibraryConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}")

install(EXPORT MyLibrary-depends
    FILE MyLibrary-depends.cmake
    DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}")
```

**MyLibraryConfig.cmake.in**

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

if (NOT MyLibrary_FOUND)
    set(MyLibrary_FOUND 1)

    find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS SERIALIZATION)

    include(MyLibrary-depends.cmake)

    # random directory stuff, etc.
endif()
```

**The issue is that `MyProject-depends.cmake` ends up with the value of `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY}`, which are both absolute paths and screw up the portability of the install.**

---

I've tried a couple of things, none of which seem to fix all my problems.

**`target_include_directories`:**

I tried escaping the `$`, with the hope that `MyProject-depends.cmake` would pick up the value of the `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable on include-time:

```
target_include_directories(MyProject
    PUBLIC "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include;\${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}>"
    ...)
```

But, of course, `INSTALL_INTERFACE` thinks that `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is a relative path and prefixes it wit `{$_IMPORT_DIR}` which breaks everything.

I can ditch the `MyProject-depends.cmake` route entirely, and add it into `MyProjectConfig.cmake.in`:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_include_directories(MyProject
    PUBLIC "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>"
    PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR};${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS>")
```

and MyProjectConfig.cmake.in:

```
include(MyProject-depends.cmake)
set_target_properties(MyProject
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

That option seems to work but is a pain.

---

**`target_link_libraries`:**

I'm having more trouble with the library linking. I tried the same trick, moving stuff into the `MyProjectConfig.cmake.in` file for more control, but

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARIES})
```

doesn't work on imported libraries, and

```
set_target_properties(MyProject INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY})
```

fails because `${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY}` expands to something like `optimized;C:/boost/stage/lib/boost_serialization.lib;debug;C:/boost/stage/lib/boost_serialization.libd` and `set_target_properties` doesn't like the keywords.

Now I'm left with some sort of remapping using

```
"$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG}>$;<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE}>"
```

but I'll also have to detect whether or not a debug library is specified... which is doable, but seems like yak shaving to me.

So, sages of the stack... any advice? Is there some obvious module or clever method that I'm overlooking?
(And thanks for making it all the way through!

---

Also: the cmake `install(EXPORTS ...)` documentation contains the helpful line "If a library target is included in the export but a target to which it links is not included the behavior is unspecified." Yeah, basically, I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the last `target_link_libraries` answer, ditching the built-in import structure entirely and writing the CMake module to remap

```
optimized;C:/boost/stage/lib/boost_serialization.lib;debug;C:/boost/stage/lib/boost_serialization.libd
```

into

```
$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG}>$;<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE}>
```

Not at all pretty, but it was the best I could come up with. So it goes.